# Required GEMS using Gulp.js and sass-ruby plugin

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

When I import

```
@import 'modular-scale';
@import 'normalize-scss';
```

in to my sass file the pre-processor breaks and states they are not found.

I've checked the gems (to see if they are installed) and have required them using gulp.js below..

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('./assets/_dev/stylesheets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ 
        noCache: true,
        style: "expanded",
        lineNumbers: true,
        require: ['normalize-scss', 'modular-scale']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/build/css'))
    .pipe(notify({
        message: "Boom!"
    })
);;
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include "compass: true", this seems to make the require argument work.

The full working code is:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('./assets/_dev/stylesheets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ 
        noCache: true,
        style: "expanded",
        lineNumbers: true,
        compass: true,
        require: ['normalize-scss', 'modular-scale']
    }))
    .pipe(prefix("last 1 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ie 6"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/build/css'))
    .pipe(livereload())
    .pipe(notify({
        message: "Boom!"
    })
);;
});
```

Edit: Although adding this made the "modular-scale" GEM work, it did not make the normalize GEM include - I believe that something is wrong with he GEM.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you've moved past this problem by now, but thought this might help someone nonetheless. I was having a similar issue with different gems `neat` and `bourbon`, and couldn't get the path configured in my `gulpfile` in order to have them recognized. Anyways, installing the gems in the same directory as my `style.scss` did the trick. Im wondering if that might solve this problem. Creating a symlink also worked in my situation; just needed to track down the proper folder within my `~/.rbenv/`.